# Display command key with keystroke package

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to write instructions for opening a terminal in LaTeX on a Macintosh. This would require me to illustrate keypresses, something I solved with the keystroke package. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find a method for illustrating the Command key. I've tried both `\Command` and `\Cmd`. What can I do to show the Command key?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{keystroke}

\title{Install Homebrew on A Macintosh}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\subsection{Homebrew}
First, install the \href{https://brew.sh}{homebrew package manager for OS X} by simply pasting the ruby script on their website into your terminal emulator. You can open your terminal emulator by pressing \Cmd + \Spacebar
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the `keystroke` package only defines

```
\Enter \Del  \Ins    \Esc   \Shift  \Ctrl  \Home
\End   \PgUp \PgDown \PrtSc \Scroll \Break
```

(with localized versions for other languages than English). You can add to the list yourself.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{keystroke}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\Cmd}{\keystroke{Cmd}}


\title{Install Homebrew on A Macintosh}
\author{Miles}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\subsection{Homebrew}
First, install the \href{https://brew.sh}{homebrew package manager for OS X}
by simply pasting the ruby script on their website into your terminal emulator.
You can open your terminal emulator by pressing \Cmd + \Spacebar

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using [`menukeys`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/menukeys). Btw: Believing the example file for the package [`keystroke`](https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/keystroke/key-test.pdf) there is no Mac command key in that package.

[image: menukeys]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[os=mac]{menukeys}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Homebrew}
First, install the \dots\ by simply pasting the ruby script on their website into your terminal emulator. You can open your terminal emulator by pressing \keys{\cmd+\Space}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `\keystroke` command from the `keystroke` package takes in any argument like `a`, `Z`, `F1` etc. It even takes in graphics as an input argument, so that's what I used:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{keystroke}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\cmd{%
    \scalerel*{\includegraphics{apple}}{X}%
}

\begin{document}
    \subsection{Homebrew}
    First, install the homebrew package manager for OS X  by simply pasting the ruby script on their website into your terminal emulator. You can open your terminal emulator by pressing \keystroke{\cmd}+\Spacebar
\end{document}
```

[image: output]