Outputting Unicode (Apple keys) in LaTeX
I'd like to create a macro that would allow me to output the Apple keys (for command, shift, etc) in my LaTeX document. I've found a bunch of answers to this question here, but I can't get them to work. Some are 13 years old, and I don't know if they still work with modern systems.
I'm not interested in entering the keys into the input file at the keyboard. I'm perfectly happy to define them by a Unicode number once, then use them throughout the document. I don't need for the characters to appear in the source .tex file, just the output. If possible, I'd like to do it without using another package, since I think the Unicode characters are already defined, and I just need to know how to use them.
The answers https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19646/how-to-typeset-special-apple-mac-keyboard-symbols and Display command key with keystroke package do not apply, because they use special fonts or packages, not Unicode symbols.
The answer
Here's my Minimal (Non-)Working Example:
%% Minimal working example to produce Apple keys

\documentclass[10pt]{article} 

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2318}{\keycmd}
\newcommand{\keycmd}{\keycmd}
%% \DeclareRobustCommand\keycmd{\keycmd}

\begin{document}
The Apple command key is \keycmd.
\end{document}

I'm using "pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)", if that matters.
Thanks for any advice and guidance. I value your experience and expertise.
-Kevin

Please link to the answers which you can't get to work.

For example the answers https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/364963/36296 all work with texlive 2024

At the very minimum you need a font which contains the unicode character. This will be hard if you don't allow using packages.

This answers shows how to do this with unicode characters: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61901/36296 (replace the font with whatever font you have installed on your system that contains the symbol, e.g. Apple Symbols)

"I think the Unicode characters are already defined," You are using the default Computer modern font that only has 127 characters

Oh, @DavidCarlisle, thank you so much. I'm using as a template the GNU Emacs reference card, which has this defined. Thanks for pointing this out.

@KevinZembower  "The answers [...] do not apply, because they use special fonts or packages, not Unicode symbols." The answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61901/36296 uses unicode symbols. The special fonts are necessary to be able to see the unicode symbols. If you are fine with invisible symbols and not being able to see the, you can keep using the default font.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, the answer provided seems to require the entry of symbols such as ⌘ in the source .tex file. I don't want or need this.

@KevinZembower The answer also provides a macro \cmdkey. You don't need to use unicode characters in your text

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, This line "\newunicodechar{⌘}{\cmdkey}" seems to imply to me that you need to type the symbol. I want to just enter the Unicode code for the symbol.

You don't need newunicodechar{⌘}{\cmdkey}. You can directly use \cmdkey in your document.

@KevinZembower Are you maybe looking for % !TeX TS-program = lualatex \documentclass{article} \usepackage{fontspec} \newfontfamily\xits{Apple Symbols} \newcommand\cmdkey{{\xits \symbol{"2318}}} \begin{document} Press the \cmdkey~key. \end{document}???

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
